# Deploy to IBM Containers without cf/ice CLI

Tags: docker, containers, ibm-cloud, wercker, container-registry

I currently have a workflow that goes like this: Bitbucket -> Wercker.

Wercker correctly builds my app, but when it comes to deploying I am lost. I am attempting to deploy to my IBM Containers registry on Bluemix (recently out of beta). 
Running `docker login registry.ng.bluemix.net` with my IBM account credentials returns a 401: bad credentials on my local machine (boot2docker on OSX). It does the same on Wercker in my deploy step. 
Here is my deploy step:

```
deploy:
  box:
    id: node
    tag: 0.12.6-slim
  steps:
    - internal/docker-push:
            username: $USERNAME
            password: $PASSWORD
            tag: main
            entrypoint: node bundle/main.js
            repository: <my namespace/<my container name> (removed for this post)
            registry: registry.ng.bluemix.net
```

As you can see: I have the username and password passed in as environment variables as per the [Wercker Docs](http://devcenter.wercker.com/docs/containers/pushing-containers.html) (and I have tested that they are passed in correctly).

Basically: how do you push containers to an IBM registry WITHOUT using the ice/cf CLI? I have a feeling that I'm missing something obvious. I just can't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Turns out: it's very possible.](https://github.com/wercker/support/issues/70#issuecomment-120198963)

Basically:

- Install CF cli
- cf login -a https://api.ng.bluemix.net
- Extract token from ~/.cf/config.json (text after bearer in AccessToken + "|" + OrganizationFields.Guid

It depends what you want to do with it. I have a very detailed write-up here [on Github](https://github.com/wercker/support/issues/70#issuecomment-120198963).
You can use the token as the password, passing 'bearer' as the username.

@mods: Is this enough for me to link to another site? I really hate to duplicate stuff like this...

Answer (score 3):

You need to use either the Containers plugin for cf or the ICE tool to login.

[Documentation](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/starters/container_cli_ov.html%23container_cli_ov)

Cloud Foundry plug-in:
`cf ic login`
ICE:
`ice login`

Can you create a custom script that can log in first? If the environment already has `cf` with the containers extension:

```
- script:
    name: Custom login for Bluemix Containers
    code: cf login -u <username> -p <password> -o <org> -s <space>
```

Excuse my wercker newb.

Comment: I don't think Wercker reads any docker configurations created in the build environment (which itself runs within docker), but I'll report back when I get a chance.

Comment: Yup - sort of. ice uses cf to grab a token, then attempts to initialize docker (wont work on Wercker). cf will save the token to disk (outside of the buildroot ;) ) so you can extract it and set it as an environment variable for the push.

Comment: And thanks - you got me started on the right track. I didn't even think to try straight up cf in the deploy environment.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the authentication with the registry uses a token rather than your userID and password.  `ice login` and `cf ic login` take care of that but unfortunately a straight up `docker login` won't work.

Some scripts for initializing, building and cleaning up images are also available here: https://github.com/Osthanes/docker_builder.  These are used in the DevOps Services delivery pipeline which is likely a similar flow to what you are building.

Answer (score 0):

You can now generate tokens to access the `IBM Bluemix Container Registry` using the `container-registry` plugin for the `bx` command.

These tokens can be `read-only` or `read-write` and either non-expiring (unless revoked) or expire after 24 hours.

The tokens can be used directly with `docker login`.

Read the docs [here](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/Registry/registry_tokens.html#registry_tokens_use)